# Symfony 4 - custom authentication FosUserBundle

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle, symfony4

Friends,

I need help with Symfony4. I building custom authentication system for FosUserBundle. (I need to convert it).

I base my actions on Symfony documentation

https://symfony.com/doc/4.1/security/custom_authentication_provider.html

And according to the documentation, I created all the authentic files. I will not throw them in because this is the same as in the documentation.

And I get this error:

> *Not configuring explicitly the provider for the "wsse" listener on "main" firewall is ambiguous as there is more than one registered
>   provider.*

This is my security.yaml

security:
    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: bcrypt

```
role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH ]

providers:
    in_memory: { memory: ~ }
    fos_userbundle:
        id: fos_user.user_provider.username

firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    main:
        pattern: ^/
        stateless: true
        wsse:      true
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
            default_target_path: /

        logout:
            path: /logout
            target: /login
        anonymous: true

        # activate different ways to authenticate

        # http_basic: true
        # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#a-configuring-how-your-users-will-authenticate

        # form_login: true
        # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login_setup.html

# Easy way to control access for large sections of your site
# Note: Only the *first* access control that matches will be used
access_control:
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/, role: ROLE_USER }
    - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

**EDIT**

*Service Provider*

```
App\Security\Authentication\Provider\WsseProvider:
        arguments:
            $userProviderInterface: '@fos_user.user_provider.username'
            $cachePool: '@cache.app'
        public: false
```

I am asking for help because I'm stuck

Thanks

Comment: I think you don't need `wsse` and you can remove it  but not sure co check if you really need it https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/custom_authentication_provider.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

on your security.yml
add:

```
providers:
    wsse:
        id: App\Security\wsseProvider #class of UserProviderInterface

firewalls:
    main:
        ...
        form_login:
            provider: wsse
```

on services.yaml

```
services:
  App\Security\wsseProvider:
    autowire: true
    public: false
```

Comment: Thanks, this is good, but I have other problem, becuase I get error ,,The service "security.context_listener.0" has a dependency on a non-existent service "App\Security\wsseProvider".''

Comment: services.yaml add
services:
  App\Security\wsseProvider:
    autowire: true
    public: false

Comment: Thanks for help :)

Comment: So, I have other problem with this provider.
,,Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Provider\DaoAuthenticationProvider::__construct() must implement interface Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface, instance of App\Security\Authentication\Provider\WsseProvider given, called in /home/www/ssh-v2-jw.dev.opcja.pl/var/cache/dev/''. This is my problem :( 
I can not solve it for a long time. I edit my post and add service with my provider.

Comment: I dunno how is your provider is working but if you use something like $daoProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider(
    $userProvider,
    $userChecker,
    'secured_area',
    $encoderFactory
); that, $userProvider must be your userEntity which is extended from UserProviderInterface instead of WsseProvider.